# Parallel programming with ManualResetEvent

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, manualresetevent

I have one method to handle a `List<string>` parallel. Unfortunately I can't use .NET 4+.

But when I run this method, `i` is always `items.Count`

```
public static void ParallelForEachTest(List<string> items)
{
    if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
    {
        List<ManualResetEvent> mEventList = new List<ManualResetEvent>();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count ; i++)
        {
            ManualResetEvent mEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((y) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(items[i] + i);
                mEvent.Set();
            });
            mEventList.Add(mEvent);
        }
        mEventList.ForEach(x => x.WaitOne());
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to achieve

> x 0 
>  x 1
>  x 2

for `ParallelForEachTest(new List<string>(){"x","x","x"});`

Comment: Weird method.  I think you should consider passing the value of i as a parameter into your parallelised code...

Comment: Standard bug, it captures the for-loop variable in the lamba expression.  [Read this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/).  By the time the thread starts running, the `i` variable has already been incremented.  Usually.  Use `var index = i;` and capture index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time when `Console.WriteLine` is executed, loop has already terminated and loop variable `i` has its final value, which is equal to `list.Count`.

In order to have each task print its corresponding index, you have to pass the index value to the task itself:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((y) => { ... }, i);
```

The second argument is the state that will be passed to the callback once the task is started.

Also, make sure not to use closure to access state from inside the task. Only use task state to transfer data:

```
public static void ParallelForEachTest(List<string> items)
{
    if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
    {
        List<ManualResetEvent> mEventList = new List<ManualResetEvent>();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            ManualResetEvent mEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                (state) =>
                {
                    Tuple<string, int, ManualResetEvent> tuple =
                        (Tuple<string, int, ManualResetEvent>)state;
                    Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item1 + tuple.Item2);
                    tuple.Item3.Set();
                },
                Tuple.Create(items[i], i, mEvent));
            mEventList.Add(mEvent);
        }
        mEventList.ForEach(x => x.WaitOne());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for clarification i'll delete my approach. +1

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, in C# 5 `foreach` was changed: in every iteration *new* variable is allocated. If you capture loop variable in a closure, C# 5 and later will give you new variable in each iteration. Prior to v 5, all iterations would capture the same variable and then with tasks that would fail. It is general advice not to capture loop variables because that may lead to strange behavior.